# En caso de validación incorrecta evitar la redirección a nueva pestaña

Tags: javascript, html, login

tengo un problema con un log in. En caso que los datos sean incorrectos quiero evitar que el usuario tenga acceso al sitio web y no sé como escribirlo en código. Les comparto lo que hice hasta el momento:

```js
function validate(){

    const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    if(username === 'Fabio' && password === 'fabio'){

        return false;

    }else{

        alert('Datos incorrectos');

    }

}
```

```html
    <form>

        <label for="Usuario">Nombre de Usuario</label>
        <input class="login-input" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese Su Usuario">

        <label for="Contraseña">Contraseña</label>
        <input class="login-input" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Ingrese Su Contraseña">

        <button class="button-input"><a href="carteleria-e-commerce.html" onclick="validate()">Log In</a></button>

        <a href="#">¿No recuerda su contraseña?</a> </br>
        <a href="#">¿Todavía no tiene su cuenta?</a>

    </form>
```

Lo que me falta es que si los datos son incorrectos no ingrese a 'carteleria-e-commerce.html'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `onclick` puedes usar `return validate()` y si devuelves `false`, no se ejecutará la carga de la página. Entonces solo debes devolver `false` cuando el usuario/contraseña no son válidos.

```js
function validate(){
    const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    if(username === 'Fabio' && password === 'fabio'){
        
        //return true;

    }else{

        alert('Datos incorrectos');
          
        return false;
        
    }

}
```

```html
<form>

        <label for="Usuario">Nombre de Usuario</label>
        <input class="login-input" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese Su Usuario">

        <label for="Contraseña">Contraseña</label>
        <input class="login-input" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Ingrese Su Contraseña">

        <button class="button-input"><a href="carteleria-e-commerce.html" onclick="return validate()">Log In</a></button>

        <a href="#">¿No recuerda su contraseña?</a> </br>
        <a href="#">¿Todavía no tiene su cuenta?</a>

    </form>
```

Comment: Aunque debo agregar que es una muy mala idea hacer autenticación del lado del cliente (pues se podría saltar fácilmente). quizás si es solo para un ejercicio no hay problema, pero no para una aplicación real. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba mejor lo siguiente:

```js
function check(form) {
        if (form.userid.value == "Fabio" && form.pswrd.value == "fabio") {
            window.open('target.html');
        } else {
            alert("Error Password or Username")
        }
    }
```

```html
<form name="login">

        <label for="Usuario">Nombre de Usuario</label>
        <input class="login-input" name="userid" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese Su Usuario">

        <label for="Contraseña">Contraseña</label>
        <input class="login-input" ype="password" name="pswrd" placeholder="Ingrese Su Contraseña">

        <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login">

        <a href="#">¿No recuerda su contraseña?</a>
        <a href="#">¿Todavía no tiene su cuenta?</a>

    </form>
```

Un saludo!